# Selecting specific and unique attributes with XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to execute an XPATH query that will allow me to select nodes based on two criteria.

First I need nodes that contain a **unique** attribute value and second I need nodes that contain a **specific** attribute value.

For example:

```
<rows>
    <row value="0" id="130"/>
    <row value="1" id="130"/>
    <row value="2" id="130"/>
    <row value="0" id="131"/>
    <row value="1" id="131"/>
    <row value="1" id="131"/>
    <row value="2" id="131"/>
    <row value="0" id="132"/>
    <row value="1" id="132"/>
    <row value="2" id="132"/>
</rows>
```

In this scenario I'd want all nodes that contain unique 'values' but only if they also have id="131". I would also want the second value='1' node removed. I would expect this result:

```
<row value="0" id="131"/>
<row value="1" id="131"/>
<row value="2" id="131"/>
```

Is this possible with a single XPATH query?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see my comment in my answer. There was a typo in my xpath. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's not pretty. There is probably a better way, but here it goes:

```
/rows/row[@id='131'][(not(preceding-sibling::row[@id='131']) or not(following-sibling::row[@id='131'])) or 
                       preceding-sibling::row[@id='131']/@value != @value and 
                       following-sibling::row[@id='131']/@value != @value]
```

Here's an example using this on a slightly more complicated version of your input XML. (I added another `<row value="1" id="131"/>` to show that it only returns unique results.)

Input XML:

```
<rows>
  <row value="0" id="130"/>
  <row value="0" id="131"/>
  <row value="0" id="132"/>
  <row value="1" id="130"/>
  <row value="1" id="131"/>
  <row value="1" id="132"/>
  <row value="2" id="130"/>
  <row value="2" id="131"/>
  <row value="2" id="132"/>
  <row value="1" id="131"/>
</rows>
```

Results:

```
<row value="0" id="131"/>
<row value="1" id="131"/>
<row value="2" id="131"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort DevNull but that query still returned duplicate values. I'm wondering if I'd be better off to query for the id and then loop over the results and remove the duplicate values?

Comment: @adampetrie - What are you using to execute the query? I tested this in oXygen XML Editor and it worked fine.

Comment: I also tested it with Dimitre's XPath Visualizer: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html and it worked as expected.

Comment: I tried oXygen and you're right, the example I give produces the expected output with your Query. The problem seems to be that my dumbed down Query for the sake of the post differs from my real-world scenario. I'll keep looking for a solution, but as far as my original question is concerned, consider it answered. Cheers.

Comment: @adampetrie - OOPS! That second `preceding-sibling` was supposed to be a `following-sibling`. Sorry about that! I've edited the xpath. Please try it again.

Comment: Thanks so much for sticking with me on this, I really appreciate it. The update works, but I have discovered another twist. It's possible to have multiple rows with the same value and id. In this case I just want one of them. Any ideas? Thanks a million.

Comment: @adampetrie - Hmm I will have to think about that one. In the mean time, you may want to unaccept this answer (maybe replace it with an upvote? ;-)) so others might look at the question and provide an answer.

Comment: @adampetrie - You should also add this new requirement to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the <xsl:key> element and the key() function. Construct a key that is the combination of the @value and @id attributes of a <row> element, and select only those 'key sets' that contain one node and whose @id attribute is equal to '131' (or whatever).

```
<xsl:key name="id-key" match="row" use="concat(@value, '-', @id)" />

<xsl:template
    match="row[count(key('id-key', concat(@value, '-', @id))) = 1 and @id='131']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Fun, isn't it?

Read more about it here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

EDIT: Sorry, I just realized you needed an XPATH query. Note to self: read the questions more carefully. However, the answer could still be useful, so I'll leave it.